# Positive function not vanishing in a neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, proof-writing

> Let $f\in C[-1,1]$ such that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$ and $f$ is not identically zero in any neighbourhood of $-1$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in (-1,-1+\epsilon)$.

It seems obvious to me when I try draw pictures, however, I'm not sure how to formally prove it. If the function is strictly greater than zero at $-1$, then it is clear. But how to treat the case when the function vanishes at $-1$?

Comment: What do you mean by positive? And vanishing? I cannot make sense of the question. If $f \neq 0$ on any neighborhood of $-1$, then in particular on the whole $[-1,1]$. If also $f \ge 0$ everywhere, then $f > 0$ everywhere.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I have edited the question to describe the terms. $f$ doesn't vanish on any neighbourhood of $-1$ only means that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $x_\epsilon \in [-1,-1+\epsilon)$ such that $f(x_{\epsilon})\neq 0$. So we only get strict positivity at one point in each neighbourhood.

Comment: Can you use the intermediate value thm?

Comment: @VivaanDaga Yes, I'm allowed to use that.

Comment: @VivaanDaga How does it help though?

Comment: What if we take $$g(x)= \begin{cases}(x+1)^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) & x\ne -1\\ 0 & x=-1\end{cases}$$and $f(x)=\operatorname{abs}(g(x))$. Isn’t that continuous everywhere, not identically zero on any interval, and yet zero infinitely often in any interval $(-1,-1+\varepsilon)$?

Comment: @Joe Oh so every neighbourhood has a zero. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem is not true, because if we let:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} (x+1)^2 \sin\left( \frac{1}{x+1} \right) & x\ne -1\\ 0 & x=-1 \end{cases}$$

Then $f(x) = \left(g(x)\right)^2$ is continuous (even differentiable) everywhere, not identically zero on any interval, and yet zero infinitely often in any interval $(−1,−1+\varepsilon)$